# Get specific rows from group by clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, select

If I've a table like below,

```
tid   pid   bid  fl fq fo
---------------------------
7114  3823  2341  3  1  1
7114  3823  2340  0  0  0
7114  3823  2350  0  0  0
7114  3850  4515  0  0  0
7114  3474  2350  0  0  0
7114  3474  2340  1  2  1
```

from this table I need to get the rows of columns `pid`,`bid`,`fl` and `fq` where its `fo=1` by grouping `pid`

and the expected output will be:

```
pid   bid   fl fq fo
----------------------
3823  2341   3   1   1
3823  2340   3   1   1
3823  2350   3   1   1

3474  2350   1   2   1
3474  2340   1   2   1
```

NOTE :for example (consider the table) 1st and 2nd row have the same pid ie.`3823` and among those two rows one row has `fo=1`(ie. 1st row) so i need to get the `pid` of 1st row and the `fl`,`fq` and `bid` of the second row,so the output should be

```
pid   bid   fl fq fo
----------------------
3823  2341   3   1   1
3823  2340   3   1   1
3823  2350   3   1   1
```

---

sample data:

```
create table com (tid int,pid int,bid int,fl int,fq int,fo int);

insert into com  values (7114 , 3823,  2341,  3 , 1 , 1),
(7114 , 3823 , 2340 , 0  ,0 , 0),(7114 , 3823 , 2350 , 0 , 0 , 0),
(7114  ,3850,  4515,  0 , 0 , 0),(7114 , 3474 , 2350,  0 , 0,  0),
(7114  ,3474,  2340 , 1 , 2 , 1);
```

Comment: What are you aggregating? Are you summing `fl` or `fq`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto  almas answer is incorrect,Need to group `pid`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto no need to sum

Comment: You need to decide what to do with the rest of the columns you select, do you want max values, or summed values etc?

Comment: @jarlh and @ClodoaldoNeto see for example 1st and 2nd row have the same `pid` ie.`3823` and among those two rows one row has `fo=1` so i need to get the `pid` of 1st row and the `fl`,`fq` and `bid` of the second row

Comment: So what has grouping to do with it?

Comment: @jarlh group `pid`.......

Comment: The general group by rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh yes i know but am confused with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

I guess you're using `PostgreSQL` Database if so then try this :

1.) Create A Temporary Table

```
create temp table temp_com as select pid,bid,fl,fq,fo from  com limit 0;
```

2.) Use [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) to get the values according to you're criteria and

**Insert** - `pid`,`bid` to `temp_com` using CTE

```
with cte as (
            select c1.pid,c1.bid,c1.fl,c1.fq,c1.fo 
            from com c1 inner join com c2 using (pid) 
            where c2.fo=1
)
insert into temp_com (pid,bid) (select pid,bid from cte);
```

**Update** - `fl`,`fq` and `fo` from CTE

```
with cte as(
           select c1.pid,c1.bid,c1.fl,c1.fq,c1.fo 
           from com c1 inner join com c2 using (pid) 
           where c2.fo=1 
)
update temp_com a 
set fl= cte.fl,
    fq=cte.fq,
    fo=cte.fo 
from cte 
where a.pid=cte.pid and cte.fo=1; -- gets the row have `fo=1`
```

And the Result : `select * from temp_com;`

```
pid   bid   fl fq  fo
----------------------
3823  2341  3   1   1
3823  2340  3   1   1
3823  2350  3   1   1
3474  2350  1   2   1
3474  2340  1   2   1
```

---

Comment: @tamirda Am not sure that my solution doesn't have any caveats but with the given sample it worked well in my environment

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select      distinct c1.pid
,           c2.fl
,           c2.fq
,           c2.bid
from        tmp.com c1
inner join  tmp.com c2
        on  c1.pid = c2.pid
        and c2.fo = 1

output:
    3474    1   2   2340
    3823    3   1   2341
```

A `distinct` is neccesary to prevent duplication, you can also `join` on more fields if you can.

Comment: From your example it appears you need the `bid` of the row where `fo <> 0`. Then what about the 3rd row where `pid` is also `3823` and `fo <> 0`?

Comment: please see my updated expected output , and yes your solution almost reached my output but need to avoid `distinct` ie. `select c1.pid,c1.bid,c1.fl,c1.fq,c1.fo from com c1 inner join com c2 using (pid) where c2.fo=1`